If a predicate doesn't determine a set, does that predicate even exist in the first place?
I thought of asking this in the Math Stack Exchange, but then I thought this stack exchange is better. Certain predicates define sets, such as "x is not equal to x". Other predicates do not, such as "x is equal to x" and the infamous "x is not a member of x". But, I wonder, if a predicate does not determine a corresponding set, does it even exist in the first place? Of course, to answer this question, we need a formal definition of predicate, and such a definition would also need to distinguish predicates from sets. Maybe a predicate is simply a first-order formula that has exactly one free variable x? Anyway, I would love to know what philosophers and mathematicians have thought of this topic.

"Equivalence classes of formulae with one free variable" is basically how classes are usually formulated in ZF set theory.

If we needed formal definitions of words to answer questions about them we could hardly answer any questions we encounter every day. "Red" is a predicate and it does not define a set, "all red things" is too vague for that. But if you want first order formulas, x = x is a predicate of ZFC and it does not define a set either. If it did, it would be the inconsistent set of all sets and ZFC blocks formation of such sets. So yes, a predicate does not need to define a set to 'exist'.

Exist where? Predicates are objects in the metatheory, and are n-ary relations over the Universe. They may or may not be elements in the universe.

You write "to answer this question, we need a formal definition of predicate" but the main problem is not the definition of predicate but rather the definition of "existing" in your question.  To avoid getting into the zillionth debate over Platonism, I would adopt the practical definition of the "existence" of a mathematical entity as having a coherent and well-developed branch of mathematics practicing the said entity, without further ontological commitments.
With that definition, I will argue that predicates do "exist", based on the following branch of mathematics: Edward Nelson's Internal Set Theory (IST).  Here IST is a conservative extension of ZFC where infinitesimals have free reign, and more pertinently for our purposes, the "standardness" predicate (indeed a one-place predicate) is part of the language alongside the traditional membership relation of ZFC.  It is seen immediately that the standardness predicate does not correspond to a set; indeed, the collection of "standard" natural numbers, which is a proper "subcollection" of N, is not a set.
There are numerous variants of IST and many related publications, establishing the "existence" part in accordance with the above interpretation of "existence".

In ZF(C), yes. Generally, ZFC proceeds by setting out a formal language of logic and then introduces the axiom schema of specification as a way to specify subsets.
So the formula x = x is totally acceptable, and we may use it to predicate sets. B = {x in A: x = x} is a valid set-builder notation, and B = A. Likewise, x not in x is a well-formed formula, and C = {x in A: x not in x} we know to be empty by axiom of regularity.
What isn't valid in ZFC is the general construction S = {x: pred(x)}, because that's (implicitly) referencing a universal set-of-all-sets U, i.e. S = {x in U: pred(x)}, which is prohibited.
Because of Godel's, we know that we can't a (sufficiently complex) formal logic system like ZF(C) within itself, so predicates are not generally regarded as sets and not representable by sets, or if they are we need to be careful to distinguish predicates outside the model and predicates within the model.

(I am not a mathematician, you should post this on Math.SE for proper answers)

Commonly, a logical predicate is an element that provides information about the subject. But that is very subjective. The notion is easier to grasp from the General Systems Theory perspective.
A system is a group of interrelated parts.
In simpler words, such is essentially the definition of a group. A system is essentially a group, which has a particularity: its parts are interrelated, which is a very subjective quality. Take this group of parts: apples, a bottle of wine and a phone call. Are they related? Perhaps not for you, but they are written in my "things to do" list over my fridge. So, in this case, the system (my list of things to do) has three parts.
Notice that the definition of system is recursive, ergo, fractal. A system is a set of parts, so, parts are also systems (e.g. "a bottle of wine" is also a system, which parts can be the bottle itself, the label, and the liquid), and systems are also parts (my list is part of the system house). Notice that the decomposition of a system has multiple approaches: a house can be a set of floors, or a set of walls.
Regarding relationships, think of this family system: a father, a mother and two kids. The father and the mother are also a system, which parts are interrelated. But the relationship between them is not unique: they can be understood to share multiple types of relationships (sex, experiences, friendship, etc.).
Now, applying such perspective:
a proposition is just a system of two interrelated parts: the subject and the predicate.
As discussed above, the predicate is just a kind of relationship between the subject and some specific object.
For example:

Sheila [subject] baked [relationship] a delicious cake [object].
The old house on the corner [subject] needs [relationship] renovation [object].
I walk. This proposition seems complex, but it is just that such structure is a linguistic simplification of what should be I [subject] walk [relationship] the walk [object]. Same happens with I sleep or I go. Linguistically, the object is taken for granted.
Go. This imperative is equivalent, it essentially means I [subject] command [relationship] you [object] to go [complement of the relationship].

Notice there is always an object. The fact that the language could hide or take the object for granted does not imply the object does not exist. Any proposition has always a subject, a predicate and a relationship.
So, a predicate is essentially a logical component that attributes a system a relationship with an object. Linguistically, the relationship is called the verb, but from a systemic standpoint, it is just a relationship.

If a predicate doesn't determine a set

Now, the term set has sense: a system is not only a set (a collection of unrelated parts), but a group of interrelated parts. What is the essential relationship that makes them a system? Metaphysically, its belonging to the set, which does not mean that they have a logical relationship. But this goes way farther: all systems are sets, so no predicate "doesn't determine a set".

does that predicate even exist in the first place?

For that, you need to define existence. This is a common definition of existence, from a systemic perspective: Does black matter exists? No, since we're still not able to interact with it.
From a systemic perspective, an object exists for a subject if the subject is able to interact (physically or rationally) with the object.
Predicates are metaphysical objects (they don't exist physically but rationally). Ergo, if you can interact rationally with such object -essentially, think of it-, it exists. In other words, any metaphysical object exists from the instant you think of it.
Think of a teenage mutant ninja elephant. Since reason abstracts everything, just thinking of the name makes it existing. You  [subject] think of [relationship] a teenage mutant ninja elephant [object].

"if you can think of it it exists" is imo not a particularly helpful way to reason about math; I am able to think about the properties that a 'lowest counterexample to the collatz conjecture' (it must be odd, if it exists, for instance.), but its existence is still very much up for debate. "a set of all sets" is something we can interact with rationally but it "doesn't exist" in most axiomatic formulations

Yes. Sometimes predicates can exist even if they don’t determine a well defined set. The relationship between predicates and sets are context dependent. In classical logical framework and set theory , predicates do determine sets but in intuitionistic logic and fuzzy logic the predicates do not always determine a set.
For instance , “x is tall” , “ x is somewhat cold “ , “x is beautiful “ etc …
